# Ef returning null, but entity exists

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to load some user info in code, but EF returns null.

```
foreach (var user in allAutoUsers)
{
    Wallet wallet = db.CabinetUsers
                      .Find(user.IdCabinetUser)?
                      .Wallets
                      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.TypeCurrency == currency);
}
```

Variable user reporting 1 wallet, but when I'm trying to get it in code above it returns null.

Are there some ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Please read [ask] and ideally provide a [mcve].

Comment: If it returns null, it shows there is no wallet for this user, in this currency.
If you think theres is. Proof it to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read more into Linq expressions rather than relying on `Find`. You can be running into issues if your relationships between entities are not defined as `virtual` which would prevent EF from lazy loading them.

The issue with using `.Find()` is that it will return the entity if it exists, however, attempting to access any related property that the DbContext isn't already aware of will require a lazy load call. This can be easily missed if lazy loading is disabled, or the member isn't `virtual`, and it can be a performance issue when it is enabled.

Instead, Linq can allow you to query through the object graph directly to get what you want:

```
foreach (var user in allAutoUsers)
{
    Wallet wallet = db.CabinetUsers
       .Where(x => x.IdCabinetUser == user.IdCabinetUser)
       .SelectMany(x => x.Wallets)
       .SingleOrDefault(x => x.TypeCurrency == currency);

   // do stuff with wallet...
}
```

This assumes that there will be only 1 wallet for the specified currency per user. When expecting 0 or 1, use `SingleOrDefault`. Use `FirstOrDefault` only when you are expecting 0 or many, want the "first" one and have specified an `OrderBy` clause to ensure the first item is predictable.

This will result in a query per user.  To accomplish with 1 query for all users:

```
var userIds = allAutoUsers.Select(x => x.IdCabinetUser).ToList();
var userWallets = db.CabinetUsers
       .Where(x => userIds.Contains(x.IdCabinetUser))
       .Select(x => new 
       {
          x.IdCabinetUser,
          Wallet = x.SelectMany(x => x.Wallets)
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.TypeCurrency == currency);
       }).ToList();
```

From this I would consider expanding the wallets `SelectMany` with a `Select` for the details in the Wallet you actually care about rather than a reference to the entire wallet entity. This has the benefit of speeding up the query, reducing memory use, and avoids the potential for lazy load calls tripping things up if Wallet references any other entities that get touched later on.

For example if you only need the IdWallet, WalletName, TypeCurrency, and Balance:

```
// replace this line from above...
          Wallet = x.SelectMany(x => x.Wallets)

// with ...
          Wallet = x.SelectMany(x => x.Wallets.Select(w => new 
          { 
              w.IdWallet,
              w.WalletName,
              w.TypeCurrency,
              w.Ballance
          }) // ...
```

From there you can `foreach` to your heart's content without extra queries:

```
foreach ( var userWallet in userWallets)
{
   // do stuff with userWallet.Wallet and userWallet.IdCabinetUser.
}
```

If you want to return the wallet details to a calling method or view or such, then you cannot use an anonymous type for that ( `new { }` ). Instead you will need to define a simple class for the data you want to return and use `Select` into that. I.e. `new WalletDTO { IdWallet = w.IdWallet, //... }` Even if you use Entities, it is recommended to reduce these into DTOs or ViewModels rather than returning entities. Entities should not "live" longer than the DbContext that spawned them otherwise you get all kinds of nasty behaviour popping up like `ObjectDisposedException` and serialization exceptions.

Comment: Thx, I remove lazy loading from wallets, cause they have more related entities inside